# Set a existing column of MS SQL table as NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to Set a existing column of MS SQL table as NOT NULL?

Comment: You might also want to add a default contraint to the column.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ALTER COLUMN columnname datatype NOT NULL
```

You will obviously have to make sure that the column does not contain any NULL values before doing this.

E.g.

```
ALTER TABLE orders
ALTER COLUMN customer_id INT NOT NULL
```

Comment: Note you must replace "datatype" with your actual column datatype, so it might look like this:
ALTER TABLE customers ALTER COLUMN address_id INT NOT NULL

Comment: @JohnZumbrum thanks for the comment. I've edited the answer to show an example.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly ensure that the fields have non null values. In this case I'm working with a field that has a GUID nvarchar so I'll do

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET    fieldname = Newid() 
WHERE  fieldname IS NULL;
```

Then as Adam Ralph says

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN fieldname datatype NOT NULL
```